# urllib.request on Python 3 failed to get certificate

Tags: python

I am writing a program which can read json of ipsw.me in python3:

```
import urrlib.request as ur
url = "https://api.ipsw.me/v4/device/" + device
json_file = ur.urlopen(url)
with open("signedipsw.json",'wb') as output:
    output.write(json_file.read())

    data = json.load(open("signedipsw.json"))
    i = 0
    with open("signedipsw.json"):
        print("signed firmwares for %s:" % device)
        for i in range(0, len(data["firmwares"])):
            if data["firmwares"][i]["signed"] == True :
                print("%s - %s" % (data["firmwares"][i]["version"], data["firmwares"][i]["buildid"]))
            i+=1
```

I used to write this in Python2 but I used urrlib2 module and it worked perfectly. Now, on Python3 I use urrlib.request but I received an error:

```
    json_file = ur.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1385, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1345, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like urllib (not urrlib) is not able to verify you're talking to the real ipsw.me. They're using Cloudflare's certificates.

You'll have a much better time using the Requests module. It comes with a more recent certificate bundle, which will likely fix your problem.

```
import requests

device = "..."

resp = requests.get(f"https://api.ipsw.me/v4/device/{device}")
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()
print(f"signed firmwares for {device}:")
for fw in data["firmwares"]:
    if fw["signed"]:
        print(f"{fw['version']} - {fw['buildid']}")
```